# Groovy XmlUtil.serialze() is throwing a 'Content is not allowed in prolog' error when trying to serialize a GPathResult

Tags: xml, groovy

I've encountered a strange issue with Groovy's (1.7.3) XmlUtil.serialize( GPathResult ) method.  It throws a 'Content is not allowed in prolog' error when I call it with a GPathResult, but groovy.util.Node is serializing just fine.  Here is the very simple Groovy Script I am trying:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xmlStr = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><stuff>ver="1.0"><properties><foo>bar</foo></properties></stuff>"""

//to pretty print GPathResult -- NOT WORKING
def gpr = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xmlStr )
println XmlUtil.serialize( gpr )

println 'trying groovy.util.Node'
//to pretty print groovy.util.Node -- WORKS
def node = new XmlParser().parseText( xmlStr )
println( XmlUtil.serialize( node ) )
```

This is the output I get:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR:  'Content is not allowed in prolog.'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
trying groovy.util.Node
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stuff ver="1.0">
 <properties>
  <foo>bar</foo>
 </properties>
</stuff>
```

I am using Groovy Version: 1.7.3 JVM: 1.6.0_20 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug where Groovy is selecting the wrong `serialize` method to execute in `XmlUtil`

If we hard-cast it, it seems to work for me (does it for you?)

```
println XmlUtil.serialize( (groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult)gpr )
```

I've added it to the JIRA here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4285  So hopefully, it will be fixed in future releases, and you won't need the cast

[edit] The JIRA now states that a fix has gone into trunk, and will be generally available in 1.7.4+

Comment: the casting worked.  Thanks for the help and for submitting the bug report :)

Comment: Glad to help :-) If this was the valid answer, can you accept it as so?  Cheers, and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You could just use [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net) as an alternative to Groovy XmlUtil.

Comment: wow Simple looks good. I'll take a look, I'm sure it will come in handy on future projects