# How do I quickly print a groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node?

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

Is there an easy way to convert a `groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node` to a `groovy.util.Node`?

I am trying to use the `XmlNodePrinter` on a node coming from an `XmlSlurper`, for some quick debugging. Here is my code (probably not the most elegant):

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse( new File( path + pomFile ) )
def services = xml.build.plugins.plugin.configuration.services
services.children().findAll{ it.artifactId.text() == serviceName }.each { config ->

    // begin section to dump "config" for debugging
    def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter)).print(config[0])
    println stringWriter.toString()
    // end section to dump "config" for debugging

    // do some other processing on the config node
}
```

This throws the following on the `config[0]` line:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node@14712c3' with class 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node' to class 'groovy.util.Node'
```

How can I quickly print out the xml representation of `config`?

I am limited to Groovy 1.7.0.

-

**EDIT**: I also tried the following but receive an error:

```
services.children().findAll{ it.artifactId.text() == serviceName }.each { config ->
     println XmlUtil.serialize(config)
```

Here's what's printed:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR:  'Content is not allowed in prolog.'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Could it be related to this bug in groovy?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151095/groovy-xmlutil-serialze-is-throwing-a-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-error

Answer (score 6):

for some quick debugging, the simplest way is to use XmlUtil

```
import groovy.xml.*


def xml="""
<a><b>b</b><c/></a>
"""

def a=new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

println XmlUtil.serialize(a)
```

Comment: You will have to povide a self-contained example that we can run in a groovy console, because I tested the above code before posting it and it sure as hell works